# Rnfirebase Notification not working when app is open react native

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native, react-native-ios

I have an app that shows notifications perfectly in the foreground and background but not working when the app is in front/open.

```
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state: 1111111-22333  app open in background' ,
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
```

and

````
  messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log('Push Notification: laveshmahajana1 ',remoteMessage)

      PushNotificationIos.addNotificationRequest({

        id: remoteMessage.messageId,
        body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
       userInfo: remoteMessage.data,
      });
    ```
````

Comment: Which firebase messaging version you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a try by using https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification npm.

For Example:

```
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {

    PushNotification.localNotification({
        title: remoteMessage.data.title,
        message: remoteMessage.data.body,
    })
})
```